# Fuzzy match between two tables

Tags: oracle, fuzzy, record-linkage

I have two tables with customer information like name and address.

```
ID  Name    Full Address
1   Anurag  123 CA USA 5001
2   Mike    ABC CA USA 5002
3   Jason   ZYZ TX USA 5003
4   Roshan  HBC MS USA 5004
5   Tony    UYS VT USA 5005

New_ID  Name            Full Address
111    Anurag CH        123  3 Floor CA USA 5001
112    Mike Martin      ABC 2 floorCA USA 5002
113    Jason Bond       ABC farms USA 4008
114    Roshan Kappor    HBC MS USA 5004
115    Tony Smith       UYS VT USA 5005
116    Anurag           123 CA USA 5001
```

I wanted to know what is the best way of doing fuzzy match between above two tables based on Full Address.  Fuzzy match should work like fuzzy Vlookup and should provide me only one best Match.

```
Desired Output

 ID Name    Full Address    New ID  Name           Full Address      Match Score
 1  Anurag  123 CA USA 5001 116     Anurag         123 CA USA 5001        100
 2  Mike    ABC CA USA 5002 112     Mike Martin    ABC2floorCA USA 5002    90
 3  Jason   ZYZ TX USA 5003 113     Jason Bond     ABC farms USA 4008      89
 4  Roshan  HBC MS USA 5004 114     Roshan Kappor  HBC MS USA 5004         90
 5  Tony    UYS VT USA 5005 115     Tony Smith     UYS VT USA 5005         90
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle? Did you have a look into Oracle Text? Have a look here https://community.oracle.com/thread/3583139 and here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#CCREF0104. The capability to do this should be there ...

Answer (score 4):

try `UTL_MATCH`  package . There are two function to calculate similarity between strings.

Steps to do.

1) Join t1 to t2 on `UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(t1.full_adress,t2.full_adress) > 0`.0 is percent of similarity. I recomende to set it to 50 or more.

2) deduplication with `row_number()`

3) returning only rows with highest similarity percent

Example

```
with tab_1 (ID,name,full_adress) as(
select  1  ,'Anurag'  ,'123 CA USA 5001'  from dual union all
select 2  ,'Mike'    ,'ABC CA USA 5002'  from dual union all
select 3  ,'Jason'   ,'ZYZ TX USA 5003'  from dual union all
select 4  ,'Roshan'  ,'HBC MS USA 5004'  from dual union all
select 5  ,'Tony'    ,'UYS VT USA 5005'  from dual),
 tab_2 (ID_2,name_2,full_adress_2)  as (
select 111    ,'Anurag CH'        ,'123  3 Floor CA USA 5001' from dual union all
select 112    ,'Mike Martin'      ,'ABC 2 floorCA USA 5002' from dual union all
select 113    ,'Jason Bond'       ,'ABC farms USA 4008' from dual union all
select 114    ,'Roshan Kappor'    ,'HBC MS USA 5004' from dual union all
select 115    ,'Tony Smith'       ,'UYS VT USA 5005' from dual union all
select 116    ,'Anurag'           ,'123 CA USA 5001' from dual)
select * from (
select t1.*,t2.*, UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(t1.full_adress,t2.full_adress_2) SIMILARITY_PERCENT, row_number() over( partition by t1.id order by UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(t1.full_adress,t2.full_adress_2) desc) rn_rank   from tab_1 t1
 join  tab_2 t2 on UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY(t1.full_adress,t2.full_adress_2) > 0
 ) where rn_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in Java that you can feed these records in and run fuzzy match. 
https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher

It does a similarity based character match and groups similar records. 
Returns the score based on similarity with different elements like Names and Addresses
But you might have a write a small java code and feed in these records into it.

Answer (score 0):

This you can easily do in Python:

1. Load the data from Oracle using the package: cx_Oracle
2. The place where you will load the data is: "Pandas" data frame (Pandas is another Python package)
3. After you have the data in Pandas data frame, you can use skLearn to compute cosine similarity for the "FULL ADDRESS" column in your problem statement. (Ref: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)
4. Cosine similarity is a value between -1 and 1. 'One' is for perfect match and zero for 'no correlation' between input string values (in your case "full address"), '-1' means string values have vectors that are mathematically opposite.
5. You have to pair those 'full addresses' that have highest cosine similarity with each other.

Research paper for reference: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XIk6v_rNbMjIWo4m6oCZOexJJ5M6xc_y